# Python multiprocessing: update shared instance attribute via manager. General ways do not work

Tags: python, multiprocess

In Python 3.7, I would like to create an instance and share&update between two processes. I have tried the multiprocessing.manager but find that the shared instance attributes are not updated. I have searched many threads but did not find an effective solution. The sample code is attached as follows.

```
class test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = [2,3,4]

    def run(self):
        while self.data[-1] < 10:
            #update the data every 1 seconds with 1 increment
            time.sleep(1) 
            self.data.append(self.data[-1]+1)
            print(self.data)

class TestProxy(NamespaceProxy):
    # We need to expose the same __dunder__ methods as NamespaceProxy,
    # in addition to the b method.
    _exposed_ = ('__getattribute__', '__setattr__', '__delattr__', 'b')

    def b(self):
        callmethod = object.__getattribute__(self, '_callmethod')
        return callmethod('b')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    BaseManager.register('test',test,TestProxy)
    manager = BaseManager()
    manager.start()
    inst = manager.test()
    inst.run()
    print ('The actual instance data is ...............')
    print(inst.data)
```

The console output is the following:

```
[2, 3, 4, 5]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
The actual inst data is ...............
[2, 3, 4]     #I expect to see [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

I am wondering why the attribute instance 'inst' is not updated. Is there a simple way to modify the code to make the code work?

Comment: Can you also post your test() method?

Comment: This isn't relevant, but can you please remove the totally pointless `getData` property?

Comment: The getData property is removed. Directly using the inst.data returns the same results.

Comment: Right, I stated it wasn't relevant, it's just very ugly and distracting to anyone that knows python.

Answer (score 0):

You should write the class TestProxy as:

```
class TestProxy(NamespaceProxy):
    _exposed_ = ('__getattribute__', '__setattr__', '__delattr__', 'run')

    def run(self):
        callmethod = object.__getattribute__(self, '_callmethod')
        return callmethod('run')
```